# jboss fuse: fabric jms discovery connection external client

Tags: jms, jbossfuse, fabric8

I have some problem with connection to activemq jms broker in fuse fabric. Internally (osgi bundle with camel route) works perfectly, but with my spring jms client have problem. I found simple demo on github https://github.com/FuseByExample/external-mq-fabric-client but doesnt connect to broker.

```
 10:55:29 DEBUG Initialized TaskRunnerFactory[ActiveMQ Task] using ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@d81f00a[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
10:55:29 INFO  Using local ZKClient
10:55:29 INFO  Starting
10:55:29 DEBUG Starting
10:55:29 DEBUG Starting
10:55:29 DEBUG reset
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:host.name=posam-VirtualBox
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:java.version=1.7.0_71
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:java.home=/opt/java/jdk1.7.0_71/jre
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:java.class.path=/opt/maven/apache-maven-3.2.3//boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:os.name=Linux
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:os.arch=amd64
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:os.version=3.13.0-32-generic
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:user.name=posam
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:user.home=/home/posam
10:55:29 INFO  Client environment:user.dir=/home/posam/external-mq-fabric-client/simple-producer
10:55:29 INFO  Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=60000 watcher=org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@7bf9757c
10:55:29 DEBUG zookeeper.disableAutoWatchReset is false
10:55:29 DEBUG blockUntilConnectedOrTimedOut() start
10:55:29 INFO  Opening socket connection to server localhost/172.16.2.20:2181
10:55:29 INFO  Socket connection established to localhost/172.16.2.20:2181, initiating session
10:55:29 DEBUG Session establishment request sent on localhost/172.16.2.20:2181
10:55:30 INFO  Session establishment complete on server localhost/172.16.2.20:2181, sessionid = 0x14fac12b2900006, negotiated timeout = 40000
10:55:30 INFO  State change: CONNECTED
10:55:30 DEBUG Got auth sessionid:0x14fac12b2900006
10:55:30 DEBUG Got auth sessionid:0x14fac12b2900006
10:55:31 DEBUG blockUntilConnectedOrTimedOut() end. isConnected: true
10:55:31 DEBUG Started unconnected
10:55:31 DEBUG Waking up reconnect task
10:55:31 DEBUG urlList connectionList:[], from: []
10:55:31 DEBUG Waiting 10 ms before attempting connection
10:55:31 DEBUG urlList connectionList:[], from: []
10:55:31 DEBUG Waiting 20 ms before attempting connection
10:55:31 DEBUG Reading reply sessionid:0x14fac12b2900006, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 1,3  replyHeader:: 1,92507,0  request:: '/fabric,F  response:: s{3,3,1441356000036,1441356000036,0,4,1,0,0,4,32573}
10:55:31 DEBUG Reading reply sessionid:0x14fac12b2900006, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 2,3  replyHeader:: 2,92507,0  request:: '/fabric/registry,F  response:: s{4,4,1441356000042,1441356000042,0,4,1,0,0,4,463}
10:55:31 DEBUG Reading reply sessionid:0x14fac12b2900006, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 3,3  replyHeader:: 3,92507,0  request:: '/fabric/registry/clusters,F  response:: s{377,377,1441356016587,1441356016587,0,6,0,0,0,6,69279}
10:55:31 DEBUG Reading reply sessionid:0x14fac12b2900006, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 4,3  replyHeader:: 4,92507,0  request:: '/fabric/registry/clusters/amq,F  response:: s{69279,69279,1441631840743,1441631840743,0,2,0,0,0,2,86302}
10:55:31 DEBUG Reading reply sessionid:0x14fac12b2900006, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 5,3  replyHeader:: 5,92507,-101  request:: '/fabric/registry/clusters/amq/default,F  response::
10:55:31 DEBUG urlList connectionList:[], from: []
10:55:31 DEBUG Waiting 40 ms before attempting connection
10:55:31 DEBUG Reading reply sessionid:0x14fac12b2900006, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 6,1  replyHeader:: 6,92508,0  request:: '/fabric/registry/clusters/amq/default,,v{s{31,s{'auth,'}},s{0,s{'world,'anyone}}},0  response:: '/fabric/registry/clusters/amq/default
10:55:31 DEBUG Reading reply sessionid:0x14fac12b2900006, packet:: clientPath:null serverPath:null finished:false header:: 7,12  replyHeader:: 7,92508,0  request:: '/fabric/registry/clusters/amq/default,T  response:: v{},s{92508,92508,1441702531307,1441702531307,0,0,0,0,0,0,92508}
10:55:31 DEBUG urlList connectionList:[], from: []
10:55:31 DEBUG Waiting 80 ms before attempting connection
10:55:31 DEBUG urlList connectionList:[], from: []
10:55:31 DEBUG Waiting 160 ms before attempting connection
10:55:31 DEBUG urlList connectionList:[], from: []
10:55:31 DEBUG Waiting 320 ms before attempting connection
10:55:31 DEBUG urlList connectionList:[], from: []
10:55:31 DEBUG Waiting 640 ms before attempting connection
10:55:32 DEBUG urlList connectionList:[], from: []
10:55:32 DEBUG Waiting 1280 ms before attempting connection
10:55:33 DEBUG urlList connectionList:[], from: []
10:55:33 DEBUG Waiting 2560 ms before attempting connection
10:55:36 DEBUG urlList connectionList:[], from: []
10:55:36 WARN  Failed to connect to [] after: 10 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
10:55:36 DEBUG Waiting 5120 ms before attempting connection
```

my jms broker config

```
standby.pool = default
connectors = openwire
broker-name = mur-broker-1
data = ${karaf.base}/data/mur-broker-1
config = profile:broker.xml
group = mur
network.password = posam
kind = MasterSlave
network = 
network.userName = posam
```

jms brokerurl

```
java.naming.provider.url=discovery:(fabric:mur)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my mistake. I use jbos fusse 6.1 but checkout  branch for fuse 6.2 from repo https://github.com/FuseByExample/external-mq-fabric-client. Version 6.1 has set other path to zookeeper registry. After checkout barnch *-6.1 resolving uri for broker working perfectly.